# Orm or RAW sql which one is better?

Tags: orm, prisma

I have a question about Orm or RAW sql

Can you tell me which one I should choose if I want to create a large-scale project? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM and Raw SQL both have their own pros and cons.
Deciding which to use would depend on your app requirements.

When using Prisma, you could use its capabilities but also have an option to resort to Raw Queries if needed by using `queryRaw` or `executeRaw` methods.

Prisma is a new kind of ORM that fundamentally differs from traditional ORMs and doesn't suffer from many of the problems commonly associated with these.

In Prisma, you define your models in the declarative Prisma schema which serves as the single source of truth for your database schema and the models in your programming language which could be a huge benefit!

Here are the cases in which prisma would be a good fit: [Comparison](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/overview/should-you-use-prisma)